# What do you call the criss-crossed elastic strap on this Northface backpack?

Tags: backpacks, terminology

This Northface backpack has an elastic strap which criss-crosses the back side of the pack. What is this type of strap called? The image below shows what kind of strap I'm talking about:

[image: screenshot of backpack]

Comment: I'd be more interested in how it's used.

Answer (score 18):

According to the features list for [The North Face Men's Borealis Pack](https://www.thenorthface.com/shop/mens-accessories-backpacks/borealis?variationId=EJH), that is called a:

> Front elastic bungee for external storage

[image: North Face product features page]

Comment: Or just *bungee,* for short.

Answer (score 17):

That's simply **elastic cord** threaded through **tie out loops** on your bag. It's used to lash everything that can't fit *inside* your bag (extra layers/jacket), things that you don't *want* inside your bag (wet/muddy clothes or sharp pokey crampons), or things that you want *quick access* to onto the outside of your bag (wind breaker/gaiters/rain jacket).

When I'm rapidly gaining elevation, I lash my extra mid layers, Goretex jacket, gaiters, crampons and anything else I'm going to be putting on and wearing as soon as we get high enough in elevation onto the back of my bag.

I lash a lot of stuff to my bag on the approach when I'm going caving, the caves here are never warmer than 4°C and most of them are up at 2000m, so you have to pack extra warm clothes as well as your coveralls and everything else you're going to be wearing through the cave. Instead of carrying a bigger bag that you end up dragging through the cave and getting snagged on everything, or sweating balls all the way up the mountain wearing your extra layers, you carry a smaller bag and lash *everything* that you can't fit inside to the outside.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

[Shock cord](https://www.rei.com/product/867980/gear-aid-elastic-shockcord-7-ft?CAWELAID=120217890000763511&CAGPSPN=pla&CAAGID=15877497040&CATCI=aud-129902659960:pla-297455113613&cm_mmc=PLA_Google%7C404_10405%7C8679800001%7Cnone%7C2e245ce1-4103-41dd-a1b3-5fa35e6a41f5%7Caud-129902659960:pla-297455113613&lsft=cm_mmc:PLA_Google_LIA%7C404_10405%7C8679800001%7Cnone%7C2e245ce1-4103-41dd-a1b3-5fa35e6a41f5%7Caud-129902659960:pla-297455113613&kclid=2e245ce1-4103-41dd-a1b3-5fa35e6a41f5&gclid=Cj0KCQjw9LPYBRDSARIsAHL7J5niYZkm__yT80REIPx_tbS2vAK6QYvZy7mqTUUV3dG0uHf5CxCrYvYaAmaREALw_wcB)

If you're looking to replace it, many retailers list it as a shock cord.

Comment: This doesn't add anything not it the other answers

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh I don't see any other answer mentioning the term "shock cord" and the question is about terminology. So I don't understand how this isn't valuable information. I agree it's short, but it's a terminology question, they tend to be short.

Answer (score 3):

On backpacks intended for cycling (including some generic commuting/school bags) this is often described as *helmet storage*, even if those backpacks have no other cycling-specific features. Bike helmets are often damp with rain or sweat, and are single bulky items that won't escape from the net.

Comment: indeed, when i used to bike to work, this is exactly what i did with my helmet once at the office.

Comment: @Jonathan you were lucky it fitted - I've never had a combination that does

Comment: another alternative is a cheap carabiner connecting the chin strap to either the shock cord or some other loop on the pack. I do that for baseball hats.

Comment: @Jonathan that's what I end up doing, but when the shock cord works it does a good job of stopping the helmet banging into things (such as fellow commuters) unlike a clip or two.